# Trouble with changing the text of an element based off of a text form .val()

Tags: javascript, jquery

My app dynamically creates and deleted new elements based on the + / - buttons. 
Inside the dynamically created elements are text forms. I want whatever the user types into the text form to be displayed in another dynamically created element.

```js
$('.LName').keyup(function(event) {
 var crazy = {};
 for (var x = 1; x < i; x++) {
  crazy[x] = function() {
   $('#sideChange'+ x).keyup(function(event) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('.sLoan'+ x).text(value);
    })
  }
 }
 for (var p = 1; p < i; p++) {
  crazy[p]();
 }
});
```

For example, I accomplished this for changing the text in the previous element by including the function in the html onkeyup attribute, but I don't know how to accurately target other elements.

```js
var changeTitle = function() {
 var loanTitle = $(this).val();
 var code = $("input[type='text'][name='loanName']").keyCode || $("input[type='text'][name='loanName']").which;
 var length = loanTitle.length;
 console.log(length);
  if(length < 1 || code == 8) {
   $(this).prev().text('Loan');
  }
  else {
   $(this).prev().text(loanTitle);
  }
};
```

Comment: What precisely is the issue you're having? Does the code you posted work as you expect, and what do you mean by you can't target other elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What youll probably want to do is data bind the two elements with some sort of ID you generate. In the fiddle below, I just use an incrementing number. When the keyup happens, I grab that elements data-id and use it to find its "mirrored" input.

```
$('.mirror[data-id="'+id+'"]').val(text);
```

Your question was a bit vague but I think this is what you were asking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/swoogie/f8cd4voz/

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking to do! Thanks! How does the data-id thing work though?

Comment: Take a look here at the W3 spec for data attributes. The general idea is that you can save some information into the DOM for later retrieving. This helps simplify your javascript logic because you dont need to write tons of code to maintain state. 
http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/global-attributes.html#custom-data-attribute